# Checking for null and set value is not allowed using `?`

Tags: c#, .net, null, roslyn

Why is setting a value using the *new* `?` operator for *pre-checking* of not null is not usable for assignments?

For example:

```
var list = // ... Some list
var entry = list.FirstOrDefault();
entry?.Value = 123;
```

This does not compile due to the error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer.

But calling a method or some thing else works.

What is the reason for this compiler behavior?

Comment: @ihimv yep I'm sure, it is a *new* c# feature.

Comment: okay i was not aware of that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# compiler could definitely make this statement work by declaring that once the chain of `?`s evaluates to `null`, all further processing stops.

The problem, however, is what to do when there are side effects on the right:

```
entry?.Value = CallSomeFunctionWithSideEffects(123);
```

Semantics of this is drastically different from other assignments, when the right-hand side is always evaluated. Here, however, evaluation of the right-hand side would need to be postponed until the left side is known to produce a non-`null` value.

Function invocation does not suffer from the same problem, because invocation target is processed ahead of parameters:

```
entry?.SetValue(CallSomeFunctionWithSideEffects(123));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `entry?.Value` might evaluate to `null`.

Then your code is equivalent to

```
null = 123;
```

which is not valid.

Comment: But calling a method would be equivalent to `null.DoSomeThing()` which should not be allowed too. For example when calling `entry?.DoSomeThing();`. Which works pretty well... Thank you

Comment: No, it would be equivalent to null (or, if the method has a return type of void, nothing happens).